# Помогите решить проблему с отображением подменю

Tags: wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему!
Есть кастом меню на шаблоне Customizr
Проблема в том что выпадающее меню на главной странице работает правильно и когда неподвижно и когда при прокрутке
https://mebelkharkov.com/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот на других страницах вот такая ошибка - меню залезает под блок когда неподвижно, но когда при прокрутке то всё нормально (игрался с position пока результатов ноль) - https://mebelkharkov.com/o-nas/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а зачем тут используется [overflow?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHlm4.png) от этого скачет меню и оно обрезает контейнер. убери эти сво-во и все нормально будет. Это сво-ство добавляет контейнеру [колесико для прокрутки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY3WN.png)

Пропиши в стилях `#tc-page-wrap{ overflow-x: inherit; }`

Comment: спасибо большое